# Element-wise constraints in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm using `scipy.optimize.minimize`'s COBYLA method to find a matrix of parameters for a categorical distribution.  I need to impose the constraint that each parameter is greater than zero, and that the sum of the rows of the parameter matrix is a column of ones.

It's not clear to me how to implement this in `scipy.minimize`, because the constraints are checked for non-negativity rather than truth.  The minimization raises an exception if I just pass the arrays as the constraint.

Does anyone know how to go about implementing these kinds of constraints?

Comment: A member of my lab suggested a trick where the last column of parameters is fixed to one, and the parameters are given by the softmax of the output.  This removes the need for the constraints that I mentioned.  Still, I think an answer to this question would be useful to others.

Comment: This suggestions not really clear, can you give more details?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first constraint `x > 0` can be expressed very simply:

```
{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x}
```

The second constraint is an equality constraint, which COBYLA doesn't natively support. However, you could express it as two separate inequality constraints instead:

```
{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x, 0) - 1}  # row sum >= 1
{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 1 - np.sum(x, 0)}  # row sum <= 1
```

Otherwise you could try SLSQP instead, which does support equality constraints.

Comment: This works, thanks!  I have separate inequality constraint, so I'll stick with COBYLA.  I've found that the upper/lower bound trick works pretty well.

Comment: Constraining only the smallest element rather than all of them is pretty smart. I'll have to remember that.

Comment: It is smart but actually will make the model more difficult to solve as it introduces a discontinuity. I.e. in general it is not a good idea. Functions like min and max are to be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen You're right - I'll remove the mins. The reason I put them in there is because [scipy's COBYLA wrapper used to *only* accept scalar-valued constraint functions](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4648). It's been a long time since I've used that solver, and I didn't realize vector-valued constraints were now supported.

Answer (score 8):

You need equality constraints that enforce `np.sum(x, 1) == 1` and inequality constraints for `x >= 0`.

However, the COBYLA method can only handle inequality constraints, as explained in the documentation of [`minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) (see the section that explains the `constraints` argument). Instead, you can use Sequential Least SQuares Programming (SLSQP), which supports both types of constraints. The `minimize` function should automatically choose the correct solver for you, based on the constraints you specify.

The constraints you need can be implemented like this:

```
def ineq_constraint(x):
    """constrain all elements of x to be >= 0"""
    return x

def eq_constraint(x):
    """constrain the sum of all rows to be equal to 1"""
    return np.sum(x, 1) - 1


constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': ineq_constraint},
               {'type': 'eq', 'fun': eq_constraint}]

result = minimize(objective_function, x0, constraints=constraints)
```

Comment: what if I have ''ineq_constraint'' returning a vector? How can I modify above?

Comment: @Waqas `x` is a vector (actually numpy array)... no need to modify anything. (Unless the code/answer is outdated by now)