# Element-wise constraints on dlib optimization

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, dlib

I am using dlib library for c++ to perform box-constrained optimization of custom function:

```
dlib::find_min_box_constrained(dlib::bfgs_search_strategy(),
                               dlib::objective_delta_stop_strategy(DELTA),
                               m, dlib::derivative(m),
                               starting_point, MIN_CONS, MAX_CONS);
```

where `m` is the objective function, `starting_point` is column vector of the initial values of the variables, `MIN_CONS` is the minimal allowed value for each of the variable and `MAX_CONS` is the maximal allowed value.

This works fine, but now, I would like to add another constraint on the variables - I want them to sum to 1. I am able to do this using `scipy.optimize.minimize` in python3 (answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631192/element-wise-constraints-in-scipy-optimize-minimize)). Is there any way to achieve this using `dlib`?

Comment: Sometimes you can get away with normalizing x before evaluating the function. A better answer is: solvers for constrained NLP problems are readily available.

Comment: Not with box-constrained optimization. You will need some form ob linear-constrained optimization (and a quick search offers nothing in dlib). Apart from hacking a "projection onto the simplex" (this is your constraint) into some bfgs-code, you probably should look for another solver. One common candidate would be Ipopt.

Comment: I meant more something along the following lines. Instead of calling f(x) for function evaluation, call g(x) with g(x) calling f(x/||x||). Same thing for the gradient. No need to change the inside of the solver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into them.